# Using a tool that can't find libssl 0.9.8 when I have openssl 1.0.2 for tool to work and receiving error

Tags: rhel, openssl

I am working with a tool(Netscout ASR) that uses a community string to access flow data in my network.  I am using this tool on a rhel7 server that has:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
```

When I run the command that is required:

```
 ./xdrexport -a xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -i 4 -Q Gn_no_filter -u rwcommunity -p read community@write community -o 4_28_2019_Gn_no_filter -s 1556456082 -e 1556456500
```

I am running into the error:

```
./xdrexport: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.0.9.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Is the tool looking for libssl 0.9.8, but because I have openssl 1.0.2k-fips it is complaining?  If so how do I fix this?

**Edit/Update**

I have tried the suggestion from below:

```
yum install openssl098e

Running transaction
  Installing : openssl098e-0.9.8e-29.el7_2.3.x86_64         1/1      
  Verifying  : openssl098e-0.9.8e-29.el7_2.3.x86_64         1/1

Installed:
  openssl098e.x86_64 0:0.9.8e-29.el7_2.3
```

It was installed but if I run the command from above I still get the same error and if I do a `openssl version` i get 1.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The version number is included in the shared library name because there are incompatible changes between the versions. This way the application gets exactly the shared library version it was compiled against.

There is an older version of openssl available that should work for you:

```
yum install openssl098e
```

This will download and install the 0.9.8e version.

Comment: I followed your instructions and said that 0.9.8 was installed but, when I run the original command again I am getting the same error and if I do `openssl version` I am getting 1.0.2k @wurtel

Comment: @sectechguy perhaps `./xdrexport` is a 32-bit application and needs a 32-bit version of the library?

Comment: That is a good suggestion I have also tried that @steeldriver

Comment: What is the output of `ldd xdrexport`? What does `file xdrexport` say? Add these to your question.